# No error message available, result code: DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What seems to be going on here? Other answers from different questions does not work for me, or am I doing something else wrong?

[image: Entire code]

Just a quick context: I am making a Signup + Login form and already finished the signup part. This is the login form code but I keep encountering this issue whenever I submit the account that is already recorded on the database.

Comment: Is the connection string actually missing the file path? + Why don't you use `Connection.Open()` / `Connection.Close()` (possibly, declare **all** those objects with `Using` statements, Command and DataReader also need to be disposed of).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put in the file path. I have followed your suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me forgot to put the file path. Thanks to Jimi for the answer!